# Make select or textarea required if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a table with multiple rows. In each row is a check box, select and textarea. If any checkbox is ticked then an option must be chosen in the select or data must be entered in the textarea.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id=" chk37179" name=" chk37179">
    </td>
    <td>B45648</td>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control reasoncmb" data-id="37179" id="cmb37179" name="cmb37179">
        <option value="">-- Select Reason --</option>
        <option value="365">Customer Changed their mind</option>
        <option value="459">Electrical Fault</option>
        <option value="458">Mechcanical Fault</option>
        <option value="457">Ordered Wrongly</option>
        <option value="363">Part Damaged In Transit</option>
        <option value="362">Part Faulty</option>
        <option value="364">Sent in Error</option>
        <option value="375">Stock Error</option>
        <option value="460">Wrong Side</option>
      </select>
      <textarea id="OtherText_37179" name="OtherText_37179" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id=" chk379" name=" chk379">
    </td>
    <td>B45458</td>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control reasoncmb" data-id="379" id="cmb379" name="cmb379">
        <option value="">-- Select Reason --</option>
        <option value="365">Customer Changed their mind</option>
        <option value="459">Electrical Fault</option>
        <option value="458">Mechcanical Fault</option>
        <option value="457">Ordered Wrongly</option>
        <option value="363">Part Damaged In Transit</option>
        <option value="362">Part Faulty</option>
        <option value="364">Sent in Error</option>
        <option value="375">Stock Error</option>
        <option value="460">Wrong Side</option>
      </select>
      <textarea id="OtherText_379" name="OtherText_379" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id=" chk179" name=" chk37179">
    </td>
    <td>B45648</td>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control reasoncmb" data-id="179" id="cmb179" name="cmb179">
        <option value="">-- Select Reason --</option>
        <option value="365">Customer Changed their mind</option>
        <option value="459">Electrical Fault</option>
        <option value="458">Mechcanical Fault</option>
        <option value="457">Ordered Wrongly</option>
        <option value="363">Part Damaged In Transit</option>
        <option value="362">Part Faulty</option>
        <option value="364">Sent in Error</option>
        <option value="375">Stock Error</option>
        <option value="460">Wrong Side</option>
      </select>
      <textarea id="OtherText_179" name="OtherText_179" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So far the Jquery I have used is as follows, it simply makes sure that they have at least selected a checkbox before they move on.

But want it that if they have ticked one the matching select box or text box has a value in it:

```
            $('#prevbut').click(function () {
            checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
            if (!checked) {
                alert("You must select at least one product to");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You've not asked a question here, just described your requirement. Please edit the question to show the code that you've attempted to write so that we can help you debug it.

Comment: I don't even see any jQuery Validate code, or even any mention of the plugin anywhere here.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you show that [you've made some effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), eg show us what you've tried, why you tried that, describe what happens, etc. We're here bcs we want to help, but SO isn't a code-writing service.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: jquery added, it makes sure they have at least checked 1 of the available boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to loop over each checkbox and look at the select and textarea that corresponds with it. Easiest thing is to add the data attribute to each select and textarea and select it.

```js
$('#prevbut').click(function() {
  var needsSelection = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").filter(function(){
    var dataId = $(this).data('id');
    return !($('select[data-id="'+ dataId +'"]').val() || $('textarea[data-id="'+ dataId +'"]').val());
  }).length;
  if (needsSelection) {
    alert("You must select at least one product to");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk37179" name="chk37179" data-id="37179">
    </td>
    <td>B45648</td>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control reasoncmb" data-id="37179" id="cmb37179" name="cmb37179">
        <option value="">-- Select Reason --</option>
        <option value="365">Customer Changed their mind</option>
        <option value="459">Electrical Fault</option>
        <option value="458">Mechcanical Fault</option>
        <option value="457">Ordered Wrongly</option>
        <option value="363">Part Damaged In Transit</option>
        <option value="362">Part Faulty</option>
        <option value="364">Sent in Error</option>
        <option value="375">Stock Error</option>
        <option value="460">Wrong Side</option>
      </select>
      <textarea id="OtherText_37179" name="OtherText_37179" rows="2" cols="20" data-id="37179"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td scope="row">
      <input type="checkbox" id=" chk179" name=" chk37179" data-id="179">
    </td>
    <td>B45648</td>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control reasoncmb" data-id="179" id="cmb179" name="cmb179">
        <option value="">-- Select Reason --</option>
        <option value="365">Customer Changed their mind</option>
        <option value="459">Electrical Fault</option>
        <option value="458">Mechcanical Fault</option>
        <option value="457">Ordered Wrongly</option>
        <option value="363">Part Damaged In Transit</option>
        <option value="362">Part Faulty</option>
        <option value="364">Sent in Error</option>
        <option value="375">Stock Error</option>
        <option value="460">Wrong Side</option>
      </select>
      <textarea id="OtherText_179" name="OtherText_179" rows="2" cols="20" data-id="179"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>

<button id="prevbut">TEST</button>
```

Comment: Can't see your code in your comment. Did you add the `data-id="xxxx"` to your other elements?

Comment: works - i had it as data_id as thats how MVC wanted it but changed to data-id now works